# MMS audio on iOS 5

Tags: ios, ios5, audio-streaming, mms

How can i stream audio from mms:// address ?
I'm trying to build WunderRadio on iOS 5 device, but i got many errors.
I got this error when i tried to build WunderRadio target:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_Status_SetNewStatusByKey", referenced from:
   -[WunderRadioAppDelegate applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:] in WunderRadioAppDelegate.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_WebAudioPlayer", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in SkinViewController.o
"_Status_GetCurrentStatus", referenced from:
  -[LevelMeterView updateBargraph:] in LevelMeterView.o
"_gStreamingAudioPlayerTimerMax", referenced from:
  -[PreferenceViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in PreferenceViewController.o
  -[PreferenceViewController makemp3Buffer:] in PreferenceViewController.o
"_Status_SetNewStatusString", referenced from:
  -[SkinViewController setShowingPlay:] in SkinViewController.o
"_CMAudioPlayerAudioIsAvailableNotification", referenced from:
  -[DebugController gotRunNotification:] in DebugController.o
  -[DebugController gotLngNotification:] in DebugController.o
"_ExpandString", referenced from:
  -[DebugController runPressed:] in DebugController.o
  -[DebugController lngPressed:] in DebugController.o
  -[SkinViewController expandString:] in SkinViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_URLBackgroundOperation", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in SkinViewController.o
"_CMAudioPlayerAudioIsDoneNotification", referenced from:
  -[DebugController gotLngNotification:] in DebugController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RadioTimeBrowser", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in WunderRadioAppDelegate.o
  objc-class-ref in SkinViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in WunderRadioAppDelegate.o
"_CMAudioPlayerAudioDidStopNotification", referenced from:
  -[DebugController gotLngNotification:] in DebugController.o
  -[SkinViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in SkinViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_EnhancedAlertView", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in DebugController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FavoriteViewController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in WunderRadioAppDelegate.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_WXRadioItem", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in WunderRadioAppDelegate.o
  objc-class-ref in SkinViewController.o
"_CMAudioPlayerAudioDidPlayNotification", referenced from:
  -[SkinViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in SkinViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_WBSettingsManager", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in WunderRadioAppDelegate.o
  objc-class-ref in PreferenceViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MusicViewController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in WunderRadioAppDelegate.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_WebViewController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in WunderRadioAppDelegate.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SettingsAndKeyChainStorage", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in WunderRadioAppDelegate.o
  objc-class-ref in DebugController.o
  objc-class-ref in SkinViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any ideas to solve this problem or others solution to stream mms:// ?

Thanks

Comment: You are not supplying enough information to help you. Overall, it appears as if you are missing a couple of implementation files in your project. Are you using a third party library or some pre made project within your app?

Comment: Yes, I use WunderRadio projects, the latest version: http://wunderradio.com/code.html 
I use this link (for ios 4.2) to build: http://jackieqi.wordpress.com/2010/11/29/build-wunder-radio-1-9-on-xcode-3-2-5-and-ios-sdk-4-2/

Comment: Are you aware that this WunderRadio project basically is a simple wrapper of FFMPEG, which is commonly known to not comply with the Apple iTunes licensing terms? -> your project will possibly get rejected when using this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"_Status_SetNewStatusByKey" is not defined anywhere (there's actually a warning about it)

You can delete it, it's deleted in the new versions anyway.